# I can't solve this problem from my calculus of variations class. We would like to find a minimizing sequence $u_n$

Tags: analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a continous and positive function, $f(\xi)>0$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the functional $F:X\to\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{\infty\}$
$$F(u)=\int_0^1 f(u'(x))dx$$
has no minimum on $X=\{u\in Lip([0,1]):u(0)=u(1)=0\}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous and integrable, it vanishes at infinity. Now, if we take the hat functions $u_n=n-2n|x-\frac{1}{2}|$, which are Lipschitz and satisfy $u_n(0)=u_n(1)=0$, we can evaluate $$F(u_n)=\int_0^1 f(u_n’(x))\,dx=\int_0^{1/2} f(2n)\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1 f(-2n)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}f(2n)+\frac{1}{2}f(-2n).$$
Use this to show that the infimum of your variational problem is zero, which is not attained since $f$ is strictly positive.